# iPhone - UIButton - background image for disabled

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have UIButton that I set the background image for three states, normal, highlighted, and disabled, all with the following format:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonBGD forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

My problem is, that when the button is disabled, the iPhone chooses to lighten the image for me. Which isn't desired. But if I tell it:

```
[button setAdjustsImageWhenDisabled:NO];
```

Then the image doesn't change at all.  How do I remove the automatic lightening of the image, and instead use just the original image I created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this are the constraints made by apple and as such there is no work around way. But u can try using the custom button and try using a bit more dark image then required in disabled state so that when it gets lightened then it is up to the mark as per your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of and ended up doing. Thanks.

Comment: You are Welcome RyanJM. I am Happy to help you. :]

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonBGD forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateDisabled]
```

If you want the same disabled image when the button is selected and disabled, then add:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonBGD forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the selected state while disabled:
`[button setSelected:NO];`